# Load another page in page and append another url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have looked everywhere for this but have no idea how to go about it.

I want to have links at the top of a page such as; News | Reviews | Images etc

When someone clicks on one those links, I want it to load content from another php file and at the same time append the link name on to the url. Example: example.com/page1/review.

I have seen other sites do this like http://www.gamespot.com/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/

I don't have any code examples because I am not sure how I would even start. I tried with .Load but not found that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), you can use either pushState or replaceState to replace the url

```
history.pushState({},"","/the/new/url");
//or
history.replaceState({},"","/the/new/url");
```

The parameters for both functions are the same. The first one is an object that gets stored and passed to the onpopstate event. You can also retrieve it by `history.state` in the event of a browser restart.

The second is a title string, i believe at the moment no browsers fully utilize it so it can be whatever.

The last parameter is the new url you want in the address bar.

So if say you wanted to load your Images link and you wanted the url to look like `/Images` you would do something like

```
jQuery("#content").load("/images.php").then(function(){
   history.replaceState({},"","/Images");
});
```

[Session History Management Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history)

Answer (score 0):

I assume since you tagged the question with jQuery, that you are using the library. Look at the documentation for the `ajax` function in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  Without seeing your code, I can't give you specific code to help you but here's an example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "example.com/page1/" + variable + "/index.php", 
    success: function(result){
        $("#div").html(result);
    }
});
```